# How do I point multiple domain names at a single Google App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, domain-name

Let GAE = Google App Engine, GA = Google Apps. Let's also say that I have one GAE account with one app, 'exampleapp.appspot.com' and one GA account successfully associated with name 'example1.com', and that I have also successfully setup 'example1.com' to point to 'exampleapp.appspot.com'.

My question is how to setup 'example2.com' to serve 'exampleapp.appspot.com'?

Theoretically this process is similar to the original setup, which requires that you 1. add domain to GA and confirm ownership, then 2. add domain to GAE, and 3. finally adjust CNAME for the name accordingly.

However I get stuck in the process at step 2. I can add the second domain to GA and confirm ownership just fine, but I cannot add the second domain to GAE. The problem is that after I click "add domain" GAE redirects me to login to GA via 'example2.com', and GA won't let me do so.

Edit: I was able to create a new account under the new domain, and login with that account from GAE. I'm guessing that this was not necessary however! Now the problem is that when I try to add the example2.com URL on the Settings tab of the GA Cpanel I get a **"We are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later. (Error #1000)"**

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy), it might help. (it worked for me)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post at least a short summary of what the content of the solution is.