# Need add secondary domain to GAE application

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an AppEngine app running at myappname.appspot.com, and I've added the URL status.domain1.com. However, the point of this whole project is have the app running at: status.domain2.com.   We have domain1.com as the main domain associated with our Google Apps account, and domain2.com is linked that account as a active domain.

When I go to 'myappname (App Engine) settings' in our control panel, and I try to "Add new URL" as status.domain2.com, I get the error banner:

```
The term &#39;domain2.com&#39; is not allowed.
```

This is even though 'domain2.com' is listed as one of the domains associated with our account, and available on the drop-down menu.

How can I get the VirtualHost status.domain2.com to work?  We already have this domain on our Google Apps account, but Google Apps support can't help.

This question is similar to [Google App Engine and domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532300/google-app-engine-and-domain-name) and
[How do I point multiple domain names at a single Google App Engine application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369151/how-do-i-point-multiple-domain-names-at-a-single-google-app-engine-application), but in this case I'm able to add 'myname@domain2.com' as an administrator of the 'domain2.com' domain on Google Apps, and I have 'domain2.com' as a drop-down option when I do "Add new URL" but I still get an error.

This bug in GAE has me pulling my hair out.  Wish I'd not gone this route.

Comment: When you created the app did you restrict access to the Google Apps domain1.com? https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/auth If so you will probably have to create a new app -- with Google Accounts / OpenId as the Authentication option.

Answer (score 6):

In order to use status.domain2.com with app engine, you have to add it to your google apps account as a domain alias and not as an active domain.

Google does not make this easy to find out, but see the last paragraph of this page: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081